# How to apply linkActive to multiple links?

Tags: typescript, angular, router, ngrx

I am using **ngrx/router**.

I have 4 pages. And two of them `/admin/dashboard` and `/admin/management` need admin access.

```
/home
/products

/admin/dashboard
/admin/management
```

I can click **User** and **Admin** to switch between user or admin views.

```
<li linkActive="active">
  <a linkTo="/home">User</a>
</li>
<li linkActive="active">
  <a linkTo="/admin/dashboard">Admin</a>
</li>
```

When I in `/home` and `/products`, I want **User** be active. Now only when in `/home`, it is active.

Similar, when I in `/admin/dashboard` and `/admin/management`, I want **Admin** be active. Now only when in `/admin/dashboard`, it is active.

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help from @brandonroberts.

> The active link is based on the path, so `/home` and `/products` can't
>   be active at the same time.
>
> Unless you have links for `/home` and `/products` under the same `li`.
>
> Then if one of those it active, it will add the active class.

So I end with this solution: using `isAdminPage` in `AdminService` inside of `AdminGuard`.

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
  isAdminPage: boolean = false;
}


@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements Guard {
  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _adminService: AdminService) {}

  protectRoute(candidate: TraversalCandidate): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._userService.checkAdmin()
      .map(isAdmin => {
        if (!isAdmin) {
          this._router.replace('/home');
          return false;
        } else {
          this._adminService.isAdminPage = true;
          return true;
        }
      }).first();
  }
}
```

Then use `_adminService.isAdminPage` to detect:

```
<li class="nav-item" [class.active]="!_adminService.isAdminPage">
  <a class="nav-link" linkTo="/home">user</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" [class.active]="_adminService.isAdminPage">
  <a class="nav-link" linkTo="/admin/dashboard">admin</a>
</li>
```